# Another time: SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device

Tags: android, linux, centos

sorry, this question has been asked before. And there are quite a lot of answers that have helped other people. In my case, it didn't work, so allow me to ask it again.

I'm running CentOS 6.x (64Bit), I have glibc.i686 installed. And I want to make my Android emulator do this (call the Android emulator):

```
/var/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -avd somedevice_android-19_armeabi
```

You guess, what's happening now:

```
SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device
```

**Measure 1:**
Ok, looking at other posts, I should install glibc.i686 (yum install glibc.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 libstdc libstdc++.i686 \
    libzip.i686 libX11.i686 libXrandr.i686 SDL.i686). Done. Still doesn't work.

**Measure 2:**
Ok, now I wanted to do some deep debugging with **strace** and got this message (just an excerpt):

```
    execve("/var/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator", ["/var/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools"..., "-ports", "48578,58389", "-no-boot-anim", "-avd", "hudson_en-US_500_480x800_android"...], [/* 25 vars */]) = 0
    [ Process PID=32558 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_500_480x800_android-19_armeabi.avd", F_OK) = 0
access("/home/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_500_480x800_android-19_armeabi.avd/emulator-user.ini", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_500_480x800_android-19_armeabi.avd/kernel-qemu", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/var/opt/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-19/images/armeabi-v7a//kernel-qemu", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "SDL init failure, reason is: No "..., 55SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device
) = 55
```

So there are some errors, but do they matter?

**Measure 3:**
I tried, what in another forum has been told:
    export DISPLAY=:0
Didn't work either. Same error message.

**Measure 4:**
export SDL_VIDEODRIVER=dont_know_the_name

Hmm, this sounds sensible. But how do I find the videodriver that are already installed, if any?

I have no more ideas about that now.
What else could I do to make that damn video driver work?
Thanks.

Regards,
Bernhard